# Error mounting Ubuntu ISO on the latest version of VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am attempting to install Ubuntu LTS 12.04 32 bit on VirtualBox however am prompted with the following error.

[image]

I have downloaded the ISO again to ensure it isn't corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely corrupt.  Check the MD5 hash of the file against the one given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: I did and it appears to be different every single time I download it although the size is not any different. I am downloading the ISOs from the official Ubuntu site. The odd thing is that I am able to install the ISO via VMWare.